# Quill js font size issue

Tags: javascript, quill

I have a proglem with quill.js regarding the font sizes.
   I have added some font sizes

```
<select title={__("Font size")} className="ql-size">
    <option value="8px">8</option>
    <option value="9px">9</option>
    <option value="10px">10</option>
    <option value="11px">11</option>
    <option value="12px">12</option>
    <option value="14px" selected>14</option>
    <option value="18px">18</option>
    <option value="24px">24</option>
    <option value="30px">30</option>
    <option value="36px">36</option>
    <option value="48px">48</option>
    <option value="60px">60</option>
    <option value="72px">72</option>
    <option value="96px">96</option>
</select>
```

And i am not abel to write with anything bigger than 18 , that means the 7th index

Also i wull i have added to the default FONT_SIZE variable inside the library:

```
FONT_SIZES: {
    '8px': 1,
    '9px': 2,
    '10px': 3,
    '11px': 4,
    '12px': 5,
    '14px': 6,
    '18px': 7,
    '24px': 8,
    '30px': 9,
    '36px': 10,
    '48px': 11,
    '60px': 12,
    '72px': 13,
    '96px': 14
  }
```

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `FONT_SIZE` constant is not meant to be changed and is set due to limitations in the browser. See the **fontSize** section of https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand. Quill 1.0 is moving away from using `execCommand` and should not have this limitation.

Comment: Thank you, is there any chance you might know when is this going to happen (1.0)?

Comment: There's no public timeline yet.

Comment: @jhchen is there an update on setting custom font sizes since you've release 1.0 BETA?

Comment: 1.0 beta has been released