# How to add font types on Quill js with toolbar options?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fonts, quill

I have made a rich text area made with [Quill js](https://quilljs.com). I have the next options for the tool bar:

```js
new Quill('#quilljs-container', {
    modules: {
        toolbar: [
           ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'strike'],        // toggled buttons
           ['blockquote', 'code-block', 'link'],

           [{ 'header': 1 }, { 'header': 2 }],               // custom button values
           [{ 'list': 'ordered'}, { 'list': 'bullet' }],
           [{ 'script': 'sub'}, { 'script': 'super' }],      // superscript/subscript
           [{ 'indent': '-1'}, { 'indent': '+1' }],          // outdent/indent
           [{ 'direction': 'rtl' }],                         // text direction

           [{ 'color': [] }, { 'background': [] }],          // dropdown with defaults from theme
           [{ 'font': [] }],
           [{ 'align': [] }],

           ['clean']                                         // remove formatting button
       ]
    },
    theme: 'snow'
});
```

```html
<!-- Style -->
<link href="https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.0.0/quill.snow.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- quill js container -->
<div id="quilljs-container">  </div>

<!-- Add quill js on the project -->
<script src="https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.0.0/quill.js"></script>
```

Currently, when I try to add more types editing the 'font' option on toolbar (e.g. 'font': ['arial']), the select options just display "Sans Serif" instead of display the "Arial" option. What I spect is see the default options ("Sans Serif", "Serif", "Monospace") plus custom options that I want to add.

Also, I have tried the [customizing attributors](https://quilljs.com/guides/how-to-customize-quill/#customizing-attributors) shown on the documentation, but with my current configuration, it just display just the default options. Maybe I'm missing something.

I hope I was clear with my doubt and someone could help me.

UPDATE:

Just to be a little more clear, I am trying to add more fonts following the **[Quill Container configuration](http://quilljs.com/docs/modules/toolbar/#container)**

> **Container**: At the simplest level, toolbar controls can be specified by a simple array of format names.

Comment: I posted a solution to add custom fonts to the quill toolbar. Please check it out.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

This is what you need.

The process is like this you need **4 components**:

1. A `select` tag with a `ql-font` class. This will contain the new font options.
2. Add the new fonts to the whitelist. This has to be defined before you call the the `Quill` constructor in Javascript.
3. Define the `font-family` for each `label` in the dropdown. Example: `font-family: "Inconsolata"`
4. Define the content font-families that will be used in the text area. Following the example in the 3rd component: `.ql-font-inconsolata { font-family: "Inconsolata";}`

**Update**:

I read the documentation in order to help you and they mention that

> At the simplest level, toolbar controls can be specified by a simple array of format names...

Alternatively, you can manually create a toolbar in *HTML* by passing the *DOM element* or *selector* into Quill; and that is the solution presented in this answer. On the other hand, the documentation does not mention but after trying many ways to *load data using an array* (without any success), I noticed that is not possible. So, here is my contribution and the reason why I posted this **update**. I made the equivalences (JS and HTML) for the manual implementation.

A *custom toolbar* can be created using *HTML* and a *JS constructor*. The constructor will receive the `#toolbar-container` as a `toolbar` in the `modules` section.

Then, you can generate the same structure using only `HTML` tags. The concept is very similar. For example:

- If in *JS* we declare an array like this: `['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'strike']` in *HTML* will be:

```html
<span class="ql-formats">
    <button class="ql-bold"></button>
    <button class="ql-italic"></button>
    <button class="ql-underline"></button>
    <button class="ql-strike"></button>
</span>
```

- In *JS* is `[{ 'header': 1 }, { 'header': 2 }]` in *HTML* will be

```html
<span class="ql-formats">
   <button class="ql-header" value="1"></button>
   <button class="ql-header" value="2"></button>
</span>
```

So, here you have a complete example in this code snippet:

```js
// Add fonts to whitelist
let Font = Quill.import('formats/font');
// We do not add Sans Serif since it is the default
Font.whitelist = ['inconsolata', 'roboto', 'mirza', 'arial'];
Quill.register(Font, true);


// We can now initialize Quill with something like this:
let quillObj = new Quill('#quilljs-container', {
  modules: {
    toolbar: '#toolbar-container'
  },
  placeholder: 'This is a font test...',
  theme: 'snow'
});
```

```html
<!-- Style -->
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
<style>
  /* Set dropdown font-families */
  
  #toolbar-container .ql-font span[data-label="Sans Serif"]::before {
    font-family: "Sans Serif";
  }
  
  #toolbar-container .ql-font span[data-label="Inconsolata"]::before {
    font-family: "Inconsolata";
  }
  
  #toolbar-container .ql-font span[data-label="Roboto"]::before {
    font-family: "Roboto";
  }
  
  #toolbar-container .ql-font span[data-label="Mirza"]::before {
    font-family: "Mirza";
  }
  
  #toolbar-container .ql-font span[data-label="Arial"]::before {
    font-family: "Arial";
  }
  /* Set content font-families */
  
  .ql-font-inconsolata {
    font-family: "Inconsolata";
  }
  
  .ql-font-roboto {
    font-family: "Roboto";
  }
  
  .ql-font-mirza {
    font-family: "Mirza";
  }
  
  .ql-font-arial {
    font-family: "Arial";
  }
  /* We do not set Sans Serif since it is the default font */
</style>
<link href="https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.0.0/quill.snow.css" rel="stylesheet">


<div id="standalone-container">
  <div id="toolbar-container">
    <span class="ql-formats">
      <select class="ql-font">
        <option selected>Sans Serif</option>
        <option value="inconsolata">Inconsolata</option>
        <option value="roboto">Roboto</option>
        <option value="mirza">Mirza</option>
        <option value="arial">Arial</option>
      </select>
      <select class="ql-size"></select>
    </span>
    <span class="ql-formats">
      <button class="ql-bold"></button>
      <button class="ql-italic"></button>
      <button class="ql-underline"></button>
      <button class="ql-strike"></button>
    </span>
    <span class="ql-formats">
      <select class="ql-color"></select>
      <select class="ql-background"></select>
    </span>
    <span class="ql-formats">
      <button class="ql-blockquote"></button>
      <button class="ql-code-block"></button>
      <button class="ql-link"></button>
    </span>
    <span class="ql-formats">
      <button class="ql-header" value="1"></button>
      <button class="ql-header" value="2"></button>
    </span>
    <span class="ql-formats">
      <button class="ql-list" value="ordered"></button>
      <button class="ql-list" value="bullet"></button>
      <button class="ql-indent" value="-1"></button>
      <button class="ql-indent" value="+1"></button>
    </span>
    <span class="ql-formats">
      <button class="ql-direction" value="rtl"></button>
      <select class="ql-align"></select>
    </span>
    <span class="ql-formats">
      <button class="ql-script" value="sub"></button>
      <button class="ql-script" value="super"></button>
    </span>
    <span class="ql-formats">
      <button class="ql-clean"></button>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- quill js container -->
<div id="quilljs-container"></div>
<!-- Add quill js on the project -->
<script src="https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.0.0/quill.js"></script>
```

Comment: **_"You cannot use the JavaScript constructor to create a custom font selection"_**; do you know if the Quill documentation mentions something about it? 
It would be even clearer.

Comment: First did you try this solution?

Comment: Second, I expend one hour reading all documentation in order to help you. They mention that *At the simplest level, toolbar controls can be specified by a simple array of format names... Alternatively you can manually create a toolbar in HTML, and pass the DOM element or selector into Quill.*  And that is the solution that I presented in this answer. So they do not mention that but after trying many way to load the data using the array I notices that you cannot. That is my contribution. That is why I posted an update with the equivalences (JS and HTML)

Comment: Yes, and it works. What you mention is very helpful. I just want to know if that is in the documentation and I ignored it.

Comment: I appreciate your contribution and the time you spent to help on this solution, but as I mentioned, I just wanted to make it clear to people who might have this same doubt in the future.

Comment: Could you be so kind to update your answer adding your second statement (related to Quilljs)  in order to make your answer as accepted?

Comment: @albertini07 I updated as you requested. Happy coding

Comment: @albertini07 I know the problem has already been resolved, but I would just like to inform everybody that, besides the official website, more information about this tool with examples and questions with answers can be found at the following link: https://github.com/loagit/Quill-Examples-and-FAQ

Comment: Wouldn't it be nice if Quill supported adding standard fonts, should be able to just list some font names in an array...

Answer (score 13):

You **CAN** use the JavaScript constructor to create a custom font selection.

From the [Quill Quickstart page](https://quilljs.com/docs/quickstart/) here's the basic HTML -

```html
    <!-- Include stylesheet -->
    <link href="https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.6/quill.snow.css" rel="stylesheet">
    
    <!-- Create the editor container -->
    <div id="editor">
      <p>Hello World!</p>
      <p>Some initial <strong>bold</strong> text</p>
      <p><br></p>
    </div>
    
    <!-- Include the Quill library -->
    <script src="https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.6/quill.js"></script>
```

The code required in the JavaScript initialiser is along the lines of the following:

```js
    let Font = Quill.import('formats/font');
    Font.whitelist = ['times-new-roman', 'arial'];
    Quill.register(Font, true);

    let toolbarOptions = [
        [{ 'font': ['', 'times-new-roman', 'arial'] }],

        ['clean']                                         // remove formatting button
    ];
    
    let quill = new Quill('#editor', {
        modules: {
            toolbar: toolbarOptions
          },
        theme: 'snow'
        });
```

You also need to add the following to your stylesheet where the names in the CSS selectors are those names in the above JavaScript:

```css
    /* Set droplist names - -item is the currently selected font, -label is the font's appearance in the droplist*/
    .ql-snow .ql-picker.ql-font .ql-picker-label[data-value='']::before,
    .ql-snow .ql-picker.ql-font .ql-picker-item[data-value='']::before
    {
      content: 'Default';
    }
    
    .ql-snow .ql-picker.ql-font .ql-picker-label[data-value='times-new-roman']::before,
    .ql-snow .ql-picker.ql-font .ql-picker-item[data-value='times-new-roman']::before
    {
      content: 'Times New Roman';
      font-family: 'Times New Roman';
    }
    
    .ql-snow .ql-picker.ql-font .ql-picker-label[data-value='arial']::before,
    .ql-snow .ql-picker.ql-font .ql-picker-item[data-value='arial']::before
    {
      content: 'Arial';
      font-family: 'Arial';
    }

    /****************************************************
    Set the font-family content used for the HTML content.
    *****************************************************/
    .ql-font-arial {
      font-family: 'Arial';
    }
    
    .ql-font-times-new-roman {
      font-family: 'Times New Roman';
    }
```

Comment: I found that fonts with a dash in the key don't work when used as the initial content as the control (via HTML). aka, had to change 'times-new-roman' to 'timesnewroman' in your example

Comment: Works when you load the font as well. in my case I had to load `https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto`

Answer (score 9):

FWIW, I've copied the code from Steve B and made it more generic. This way you don't need to do all the copy pasting of css rules, etc... just specify the fonts you would like adding in your fonts array.

```
// specify the fonts you would 
var fonts = ['Arial', 'Courier', 'Garamond', 'Tahoma', 'Times New Roman', 'Verdana'];
// generate code friendly names
function getFontName(font) {
    return font.toLowerCase().replace(/\s/g, "-");
}
var fontNames = fonts.map(font => getFontName(font));
// add fonts to style
var fontStyles = "";
fonts.forEach(function(font) {
    var fontName = getFontName(font);
    fontStyles += ".ql-snow .ql-picker.ql-font .ql-picker-label[data-value=" + fontName + "]::before, .ql-snow .ql-picker.ql-font .ql-picker-item[data-value=" + fontName + "]::before {" +
        "content: '" + font + "';" +
        "font-family: '" + font + "', sans-serif;" +
        "}" +
        ".ql-font-" + fontName + "{" +
        " font-family: '" + font + "', sans-serif;" +
        "}";
});
var node = document.createElement('style');
node.innerHTML = fontStyles;
document.body.appendChild(node);

var toolbarOptions = [
    ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'strike'],        // toggled buttons
    ['blockquote', 'code-block'],

    [{ 'header': 1 }, { 'header': 2 }],               // custom button values
    [{ 'list': 'ordered'}, { 'list': 'bullet' }],
    [{ 'script': 'sub'}, { 'script': 'super' }],      // superscript/subscript
    [{ 'indent': '-1'}, { 'indent': '+1' }],          // outdent/indent
    [{ 'direction': 'rtl' }],                         // text direction

    [{ 'size': ['small', false, 'large', 'huge'] }],  // custom dropdown
    [{ 'header': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, false] }],

    [{ 'color': [] }, { 'background': [] }],          // dropdown with defaults from theme
    [{ 'font': fontNames }],
    [{ 'align': [] }],

    ['clean']                                         // remove formatting button
];

// Add fonts to whitelist
var Font = Quill.import('formats/font');
Font.whitelist = fontNames;
Quill.register(Font, true);

var quill = new Quill('#editor', {
    modules: {
        toolbar: toolbarOptions
    },
    theme: 'snow'
});
```

Answer (score 7):

Had to make some updates to @Thomas' answer, but the code below automates things nicely in Quill v1.3.6.  If you have a short list of fonts then the required CSS is trivial; but if you have a larger and/or dynamic list you'll want to automate as follows:

```
// Specify Quill fonts
var fontList = ['Arial', 'Courier', 'Garamond', 'Tahoma', 'Times New Roman', 'Verdana'];
var fontNames = fontList.map(font => getFontName(font));
var fonts = Quill.import('attributors/class/font');
fonts.whitelist = fontNames;
Quill.register(fonts, true);

// Add fonts to CSS style
var fontStyles = "";
fontList.forEach(function(font) {
    var fontName = getFontName(font);
    fontStyles += ".ql-snow .ql-picker.ql-font .ql-picker-label[data-value=" + fontName + "]::before, .ql-snow .ql-picker.ql-font .ql-picker-item[data-value=" + fontName + "]::before {" +
        "content: '" + font + "';" +
        "font-family: '" + font + "', sans-serif;" +
        "}" +
        ".ql-font-" + fontName + "{" +
        " font-family: '" + font + "', sans-serif;" +
        "}";
});

// Configure Quill editor options
var toolbarOptions = [
    [{ 'font': fonts.whitelist }],
    ['bold', 'italic', 'underline'],
    ['clean'] 
];

var quill;
$(function() {
    // Append the CSS stylesheet to the page
    var node = document.createElement('style');
    node.innerHTML = fontStyles;
    document.body.appendChild(node);

    quill = new Quill('#editor', {
    theme: 'snow',
    modules: {
        toolbar: toolbarOptions
    } 
    });
});

// Generate code-friendly font names
function getFontName(font) {
    return font.toLowerCase().replace(/\s/g, "-");
}
```

The relevant link to the Quill docs is https://quilljs.com/guides/how-to-customize-quill/#customizing-attributors, although the examples provided here are rather incomplete.

Comment: I took your example and transposed it into react with Class Components in typescript. I had fun with the typings.

Answer (score 4):

Accepted answer is mostly great but it's important to notice, that `formats/font` is actually wrong and doesn't work with tested *Quill 1.3.7*.

What **worked** for me was:

<s>`let fonts = Quill.import("formats/font");`</s>

```
let fonts = Quill.import("attributors/style/font");
fonts.whitelist = ["initial", "sans-serif", "serif", "monospace"];
Quill.register(fonts, true);
```

Answer (score 2):

Was able to get to this code thanks to this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64827265) . I found a better answer, just update your js and css with the code I have below

```js
// add an array of values
const fontFamilyArr = ["Roboto Condensed", "Times New Roman", "Calibri", "Calibri Light", "Sans-Serif"];
let fonts = Quill.import("attributors/style/font");
fonts.whitelist = fontFamilyArr;
Quill.register(fonts, true);

const fontSizeArr = ['10px', '11px', '12px', '14px', '18px', '24px'];
var Size = Quill.import('attributors/style/size');
Size.whitelist = fontSizeArr;
Quill.register(Size, true);

var toolbarOptions = [
  [{
    'size': fontSizeArr
  }],
  [{
    'font': fontFamilyArr
  }]
];

var quill = new Quill('#mail-body-editor', {
  modules: {
    toolbar: toolbarOptions
  },
  theme: 'snow',
  placeholder: 'Please provide the content of your mail here'
});
```

```css
/*Adding the values from the array which has the values as data-values*/


/*for font-size*/

.ql-snow .ql-picker.ql-size .ql-picker-label[data-value]::before,
.ql-snow .ql-picker.ql-size .ql-picker-item[data-value]::before {
  content: attr(data-value) !important;
}


/*for font-family*/

.ql-snow .ql-picker.ql-font .ql-picker-label[data-value]::before,
.ql-snow .ql-picker.ql-font .ql-picker-item[data-value]::before {
  content: attr(data-value) !important;
}

.ql-snow .ql-picker.ql-font {
  width: 150px !important;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<body>
  <link href="//cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.6/quill.snow.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="//cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.6/quill.bubble.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="//cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.6/quill.min.js"></script>
  <div id="mail-body-editor"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hey, welcome to StackOverflow! Could you please edit your post for more details? Why is your answer the correct answer?

Comment: hey @ChrisvanChip, in the accepted answer we have to add html code along with the necessary font-styling through css, with the method I've mentioned, you have to just provide an array of font-names which u need and initialise it and you're done. Hope this clarifies my post