# Add fonts in Quill editor Angular 2+

Tags: javascript, angular, quill, ngx-quill

I am using quill editor in angular I am unable to add multiple fonts in angular 2+
I am using following code snippet

```
QuillModule.forRoot({
      modules: {
        toolbar: [
          ['blockquote', 'code-block'],

          // [{ 'header': 1 }, { 'header': 2 }],               // custom button values
          [{ 'list': 'ordered' }, { 'list': 'bullet' }],
          // [{ 'script': 'sub' }, { 'script': 'super' }],      // superscript/subscript
          [{ 'indent': '-1' }, { 'indent': '+1' }],          // outdent/indent
          [{ 'direction': 'rtl' }],                         // text direction

          [{ 'size': ['small', false, 'large', 'huge'] }],  // custom dropdown
          [{ 'header': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, false] }],

          [{ 'color': [] }, { 'background': [] }],          // dropdown with defaults from theme
          [{ 'font': [] }],
          [{ 'align': [] }],

          ['clean'],                                         // remove formatting button

          ['link', 'image']                         // link and image, video
        ]
      },

    })
```

when ever I add fonts in fonts list I get same font all the time. I followed this link as well but its not for angular I suppose
[How to add font types on Quill js with toolbar options?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43728080/how-to-add-font-types-on-quill-js-with-toolbar-options)

can anyone help me?

Comment: Please [add a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as a starting point in code.

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem like this.

**First, you must define your fonts in the whitelist.**

```
import Quill from 'quill';

const FontAttributor = Quill.import('attributors/class/font');
FontAttributor.whitelist = [
  'IRANSans',
  'roboto',
  'cursive',
  'fantasy',
  'monospace'
];
Quill.register(FontAttributor, true);
```

**Then you have to add the fonts to the config inside your component.**

```
quillConfig: QuillModules = {
    toolbar: {
      container: [
        ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'strike'],
        [{ size: ['small', false, 'large', 'huge'] }],
        [{ font: ['IRANSans', 'roboto', 'cursive', 'fantasy', 'monospace'] }],
        [{ align: [] }],
        ['clean'],
        ['link'],
      ]
    }
  };
```

**By applying these changes, your fonts will be added to the list of fonts and will get the data-value attribute.**

[image]

**After that, you need to add a series of styles to the app.**

```
.ql-snow .ql-picker-options .ql-picker-item {
  font-family: #{attr(data-value)};
  &::before {
    content: attr(data-value) !important;
  }
}

.ql-snow .ql-picker.ql-font .ql-picker-label::before,
.ql-snow .ql-picker.ql-font .ql-picker-item::before {
  content: attr(data-value) !important;
}
```

Finally, to apply the font-family on the text inside the editor, you can use sass,sccs like this.

```
$text-editor-fonts: 'IRANSans', 'roboto', 'cursive', 'fantasy', 'monospace';

@each $text-editor-font in $text-editor-fonts {
  .ql-font-#{$text-editor-font} {
    font-family: $text-editor-font;
  }
}
```

Comment: It works for fonts with name from one word. If you try "Times New Roman" the data attribute won't be applied, so the font won't work as well. A solution for this can be found here: https://github.com/quilljs/quill/issues/598

Answer (score 0):

A select tag with a `ql-font` class. This will contain the new font options.Add the new fonts to the whitelist. This has to be defined before you call the Quill constructor in Javascript.Define the font-family for each label in the dropdown. Example:

```
font-family: "Inconsolata"
```

Define the content font-families that will be used in the text area. Following the example in the 3rd component: `.ql-font-inconsolata` { font-family: "Inconsolata";}