# How to remove or change the default font in Quill js?

Tags: javascript, quill

No matter how I tried to remove the default "Sans serif" font from the font selection in Quill js it kept appearing.

Even if I removed it from  it kept appearing

[image]

As you can see in the picture the font is present even if not in the select which is something like:

```html
     <select class="ql-font">
        <option selected>SourceSansPro</option>
        <option value="inconsolata">Inconsolata</option>
        <option value="roboto">Roboto</option>
        <option value="mirza">Mirza</option>
        <option value="arial">Arial</option>
      </select>
```

So how do I get rid of it?

Note: I used this question: [How to add font types on Quill js with toolbar options?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43728080/how-to-add-font-types-on-quill-js-with-toolbar-options) as guide.

Answer (score 1):

From the SO link you provided, I consolidated the answers to register the fonts dynamically and it can override the default font list completely.

You can try the code snippet below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
    <link href="https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.6/quill.snow.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro%7CRoboto%7CInconsolata%7CMirza"
        rel="stylesheet">

    <style>
        #editor-container {
            width: 100%;
            max-width: 1000px;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
        }

        /* to avoid overflow for long font name */
        .ql-formats:nth-child(1) {
            width: 130px;
        }

        /* expand to ql-format width */
        .ql-snow .ql-picker.ql-font {
            width: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="toolbar-container" class="ql-toolbar ql-snow">
        <span class="ql-formats">
            <select class="ql-font">
                <option value="source-sans-pro" selected></option>
                <option value="inconsolata"></option>
                <option value="roboto"></option>
                <option value="mirza"></option>
                <option value="arial"></option>
            </select>
        </span>
        <span class="ql-formats">
            <select class="ql-header">
                <option value="1"></option>
                <option value="2"></option>
                <option value="3"></option>
                <option selected="selected"></option>
            </select>
        </span>
        <span class="ql-formats">
            <button type="button" class="ql-bold"></button>
        </span>
        <span class="ql-formats">
            <button type="button" class="ql-list" value="ordered"></button>
            <button type="button" class="ql-list" value="bullet"></button>
        </span>
        <span class="ql-formats">
            <button type="button" class="ql-clean"></button>
        </span>
    </div>

    <div id="editor-container">
        <div id="editor">
            <p>
                He has since been seeking advice from specialists, including Serbian doctor Zdenko Milinkovic, who said
                Djokovic is suffering
                from a "bruised bone due to excessive playing".
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.6/quill.js"></script>
    <script>
        const getFontName = (font) => font.toLowerCase().replace(/\s/g, "-");
        const fontNameList = ['Source Sans Pro', 'Inconsolata', 'Roboto', 'Mirza', 'Arial'];
        const fontNameLowercaseList = fontNameList.map(font => getFontName(font));

        // register fonts in quill
        const fonts = Quill.import("formats/font");
        fonts.whitelist = fontNameLowercaseList
        Quill.register(fonts, true);

        const quill = new Quill('#editor', {
            theme: 'snow',
            modules: {
                toolbar: {
                    container: '#toolbar-container'
                }
            }
        });

        // Add extra font CSS to the DOM dynamically
        const node = document.createElement('style');
        node.innerHTML = fontNameList.reduce((fontStyle, fontName) => {
            const fontNameLowercase = getFontName(fontName);
            fontStyle += `
                .ql-snow .ql-picker.ql-font .ql-picker-label[data-value=${fontNameLowercase}]::before,
                .ql-snow .ql-picker.ql-font .ql-picker-item[data-value=${fontNameLowercase}]::before {
                    content: '${fontName}';
                    font-family: '${fontName}';
                }

                .ql-font-${fontNameLowercase} {
                    font-family: '${fontName}';
                }
            `
            return fontStyle
        }, '')
        document.body.appendChild(node);
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The problem with the snippet is that if you select a word and change it to Roboto and then select a different word (with font untouched so presumably Source Sans Pro) it does not change to that font (Source Sans Pro) but stay as Roboto.

Comment: ok. get your point. updated the snippet to construct the toolbar manually to have source-sans-pro be selected to be the default font so the changes of font will behave like quilljs example.

Answer (score 1):

Try overriding the `ql-editor` class in your CSS file:

```
.ql-editor {
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
}
```

[Source](https://github.com/quilljs/quill/issues/2899#issuecomment-904798129)