How to add Fonts to Quill Editor using Angular
I have an Angular 18 Application and using Quill Richtext Editor. How to add a font, let say 'Roboto' ?
export const quillConfiguration = {
  toolbar: [
    ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'strike'],        // toggled buttons

    [{'header': 1}, {'header': 2}],               // custom button values
    [{'list': 'ordered'}, {'list': 'bullet'}],
    [{'indent': '-1'}, {'indent': '+1'}],          // outdent/indent
    [{'direction': 'rtl'}],                         // text direction

    [{'size': ['small', false, 'large', 'huge']}],  // custom dropdown
    [{'header': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, false]}],

    [{'color': []}, {'background': []}],          // dropdown with defaults from theme
    [{'font': []}],
    [{'align': []}],

    ['clean'],                                         // remove formatting button
  ]
}


And my html component.
  <quill-editor
    (onContentChanged)="onContentChanged($event)"
    [(ngModel)]="moEditorDocument.content"
    [modules]="quillConfiguration"
    [placeholder]="'Placeholder...'"
    class="rich-text-editor"
    id="rich-text-editor"
  >
  </quill-editor>


Hopefully this will help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43728080/how-to-add-font-types-on-quill-js-with-toolbar-options

I finnaly solved it. I created a fully working git repository with Angular 18
https://github.com/Samyssmile/quill-angular-example
Quill Rich Text Editor in Angular with custom fonts

Steps to integrate Quill Editor in Angular with custom fonts.
I will use FiraCode font in this example. As it is the best font in entire universe.
Prepare, download fonts
Link to download FiraCode font: https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode
FiraCode-Regular.ttf is in /public folder.
Install ngx-quill
npm install ngx-quill

Create a toolbar configuration. Pay attention to the font property. I added 'firacode' there.
const modules = {
  toolbar: [
    ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'strike'],        // toggled buttons
    ['blockquote', 'code-block'],

    [{'header': 1}, {'header': 2}],               // custom button values
    [{'list': 'ordered'}, {'list': 'bullet'}],
    [{'script': 'sub'}, {'script': 'super'}],      // superscript/subscript
    [{'indent': '-1'}, {'indent': '+1'}],          // outdent/indent
    [{'direction': 'rtl'}],                         // text direction

    [{'size': ['small', false, 'large', 'huge']}],  // custom dropdown
    [{'header': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, false]}],

    [{'color': []}, {'background': []}],          // dropdown with defaults from theme
    [{'font': ['firacode']}],
    [{'align': []}],

    ['clean'],                                         // remove formatting button

    ['link', 'image', 'video']                         // link and image, video
  ]
};


Add quill-editor tag

<quill-editor
  format="text"
  [(ngModel)]="content"
  [modules]="quillConfiguration"
  (onContentChanged)="onContentChanged($event)"
  [placeholder]="'Winter is coming...'"

></quill-editor>

Prepare Styling
Extend your angular.json file with the following styles.
  "styles": [
"src/styles.scss",
"quill/dist/quill.core.css",
"quill/dist/quill.snow.css"
]

Add styling to your global styles.scss file.
[quill-editor-toolbar] .ql-font span[data-label="Fira Code"]::before {
  font-family: "Fira Code";
}

.ql-font-firacode {
  font-family: "Fira Code";
}

.ql-snow .ql-picker.ql-font .ql-picker-label[data-value=firacode]::before, .ql-snow .ql-picker.ql-font .ql-picker-item[data-value=firacode]::before {
  content: 'Fira Code';
}

Add provider into app.config.ts

provideQuillConfig({
  customOptions: [{
    import: 'formats/font',
    whitelist: ['firacode', 'roboto', 'serif', 'monospace']
  }]
})


Embed fonts in your index.html file.
Google Roboto Example

<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fira+Code" rel="stylesheet">

you also need to repeat css steps for roboto.
