# Angular 6 PrimeNG custom editor

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng, quill

I am trying to customize my `PrimeNG Editor` I'm having adding a select dropdown list with custom font sizes `[12px, 14px, 16px...]`

Here is the component `HTML`

```
<p-editor [(ngModel)]="value" (onTextChange)="onTextChanged($event)">
            <p-header>
                    <span class="ql-formats">
                     ...
                      <select class="ql-size">
                            <option value="12px">12</option>
                            <option value="14px">14</option>
                            <option value="16px">16</option>
                        </select>
                    </span>
                   ...
                  </p-header>               
    </p-editor>
```

I can get the select list to show with all the font sizes
[image]

I'm not sure how to add the functionality to change the font size when selecting an option in the list. I don't see any examples in their docs for typescript. How can I make a select list of custom font sizes?

[Here are the docs I followed](https://quilljs.com/docs/modules/toolbar/)

[example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/quill-editor-z1sxxu?file=angular.json)

Comment: Can you provide a working stackblitz demo?

Comment: @ConnorsFan Sure thing!

Comment: Check how to do it on quill https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38623716/how-to-add-custom-font-sizes-to-quilljs-editor

Comment: @ConnorsFan Updated!

Comment: @erw13n I've tried that but it doesn't seem to work in Typescript.

Comment: @OrthoHomeDefense your code is fine, uncomment the "constructor" and import Quill as follow "declare const Quill: any;" https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/7526#issuecomment-325804143

Comment: @erw13n Thanks, it wasn't working before. I was declaring Quill as `import * as Quill from 'quill'` After changing it to your suggestion it started to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly,put your component.ts

```
import { Editor } from 'primeng/editor';
declare var Quill: any;
```

and add this line in constructor

```
var fontSizeStyle = Quill.import('attributors/style/size');
fontSizeStyle.whitelist = ['24px', '48px', '100px', '200px'];
Quill.register(fontSizeStyle, true);
```

At the last,change your html

```
<span class="ql-formats">
   <select class="ql-size">
       <option value="24px">24</option>
       <option value="48px">48</option>
       <option value="100px">100</option>
       <option value="200px">200</option>
   </select>
</span>
```

[Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/quill-55477705-a4pkrt)

Answer (score 0):

First get the style/size  whitelisted in the `.ts`:

```
constructor(){
    var fontSizeStyle = Quill.import('attributors/style/size');
    fontSizeStyle.whitelist = ['0.75em','1em','1.5em','2.5em', '24px', '48px', '100px', '200px'];
    Quill.register(fontSizeStyle, true);
}
```

Now in the `html` file we used this whitelisted options:

```
<span class="ql-formats">
   <select class="ql-size">
     <option value="0.75em">small</option>
     <option value="1em" selected></option>
     <option value="1.5em">large</option>
     <option value="2.5em">huge</option>
   </select>
 </span>
 <span class="ql-formats">
   <select class="ql-size">
      <option value="24px">24</option>
      <option value="48px">48</option>
      <option value="100px">100</option>
      <option value="200px">200</option>
    </select>
 </span>
```

Check the change of the value of the first dropdown options.

You can declare the var Quill so it doesn't have problems with the undefined variable: (this is how primeng does it too)

```
declare var Quill: any;
```

Working example here:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/quill-55477705?file=src/app/app.component.ts